# UML class diagram - represent attribute with initial value

Tags: class, uml, diagram

How is an attribute with initial value (such as a static constant) represented in UML?

```
public class Foo {
    public static final int BAR = 17;
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The initial value of an attribute in a UML class diagram is represented just like variable assignment in a language like Java.

[image]

Moreover, since the example attribute is static, it should be underlined. Capitalization is by language or other convention and is not a UML specification.

Comment: UML does not say anything about capitalizing names of constants.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what software are you using?

Comment: That screenshot I'm pretty certain came from Microsoft Visio 2010. Nowadays I would go for the free and less capable Lucidcharts. I never need UML outside of teaching

Comment: @ThisClark plantuml is an interesting alternative for simple diagrams. (It is text based, with automated layout.)

Comment: @ThisClark. Hello, Can i define size of array? For example: -array:Array<Int>. I write my uml class from Kotlin class.

Comment: I think you can do one multiplicity like this: `- array : Array<Int>[0...10]` or just a fixed size like this `- array : Array<Int>[10]`